# Cookieless domains for static in Django + Nginx

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-deployment, django-static, django-dev-server

I've found a tip of using cookieless domains for serving static files. My experiments have shown seriuos drop in request time (django-debug-toolbar) that is pretty much what I wanted to get.

The problem is that I want to add '`http://static.xxxxx.com`' to each static file request (e.g. `<img src="http://static.xxxxx.com/..."/>`, but hold all the files at the same place as they are now (using CNAME).

However I'm not sure about what should I change in production: either nginx conf or django settings.. I've tried changing `STATIC_URL` adding `http://static.xxxxxx.com`, but in vain - everything has crushed.

Could you help me with an advice?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day